# Fixed Sidebar with margin top and margin bottom

Tags: html, css

Basically I tried to build a sidebar which has some spaces on top and bottom but I couldn't get at the bottom. Here is a pic [sidebar has top spaces but not bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTQ2i.png)

and here is my css code

```
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 14px;
  left: 20px;
  //bottom: 14px;
  width: 7.375rem;
  height: 100%;
  // margin-bottom: 14px;
  border-radius: 1.8125rem;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

How can I achieve like the sidebar has space too at the bottom as top. I tried to gave a margin to bottom and also setting the bottom but I didn't get it.

Comment: Hey man! Have you tried adding a padding? 
padding-bottom: 14px;

Comment: It's tricky to give a really good answer, without seeing the context of your entire page.

Comment: show more code, pls

Answer (score 1):

Could simply add an extra container as a wrap container and use `padding`.

using `calc` means you are strict to specify the amount of top/bottom you wish to have.

heres a quick example:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap {
  width: 7.375rem;
  left: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.sidebar {
  border-radius: 1.8125rem;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
}
```

This way, the container with class `wrap` sets the limits of the inner container `sidebar` and `padding`, in the `wrap` container, limits so the inner container to be `20px` from the top and bottom. `box-sizing: border-box` is IMPOSTANT tho, either apply it to everything, like in my example, or just the `wrap` class. Without it, the child element with `height: 100%` would take the entire parents height + 40px for top and bottom padding. What this does is similar to what `calc` would do just automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Having the height set to 100% is causing problems here.

You could try using calc, to set the height to 100%, minus the top and bottom space that you want, for example:

```
height: calc(100% - 28px);
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. Its awesome. how could I not think of this. Great thanks